# Incorrect calculation output

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to create a simple form for calculating speed, distance and time traveled, but the calculations come out wrong.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace _2ndTask
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        double speed, time, distance, laiks, garums, atrums; // laiks = time2, garums = distance2, atrums = speed2

        private void label1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bool timeInput = double.TryParse(textBox3.Text, out laiks);
            
            if (!timeInput || laiks < 0 || laiks > 9999)
            {
                // MessageBox.Show("Ignorēt šo paziņojumu.");
            }
            // timeInput = float.Parse (textBox3.Text);
            
            
        }   


        private void textBox2_TextChanged2(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            
            bool cGarumsInput = double.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out garums);

            if (!cGarumsInput || garums < 0 || garums > 999999)
            {
                // MessageBox.Show("Ignorēt šo paziņojumu.");
            }
            

        }
        private void textBox1_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            bool speedInput = double.TryParse(textBox3.Text, out atrums);

            if (!speedInput || atrums < 0 || atrums > 9999)
            {
                // MessageBox.Show("Ignorēt šo paziņojumu.");
            
            } 
            
        }
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            time = (garums / atrums);
            label4.Text = time.ToString();
        }

        private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            distance = atrums * laiks;
            label4.Text = distance.ToString() + " Km.";
        }
        
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            speed = garums / laiks;
            label4.Text = speed.ToString() + " Km/h.";

        }
    }
}
```

Before I added TryParse the calculations were correct, but the forms would crash whenever  values would be deleted from textboxes.

It should output 140 underneath (multiply time and speed) instead it outputs 49. Inputting other numbers also gives wrong result

[image]

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266563/do-non-english-words-increase-the-probability-of-receiving-downvotes/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo. You are assigning the text from textBox3 to both atrums and laiks. Presumably one of them should use the text from textBox1.